# PuTTY psftp get file from partial name

Tags: batch-file, sftp, putty, psftp

One of our suppliers has started sending reports where the filename is suffixed with the date of the export and I can't work out using PuTTY psftp how to always pick up the file regardless of the change in file name.

```
This works for the exact file
get "TBD_7dayExport_20190628.csv"

What I'm looking to do is something like:
get "TBD_7dayExport" %
```

My aim is to pick up a new dated file every day, import and rename to `TBD_7dayExport`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mget` command](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-cmd-mgetput) with a wildcard:

```
mget TBD_7dayExport_*.csv
```

But it won't allow you to rename the file to a fixed name. You would have to use some fancy batch file construct post-download. Something like this:
[Removing part of filename with batch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37863134/850848)

---

Or use a more powerful SFTP client, which supports renaming files while transferring them.

For example with *my* [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/), you can do:

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=download.log /command ^
    "open sftp://user:password@example.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxx...=""" ^
    "get TBD_7dayExport_*.csv TBD_7dayExport.csv" ^
    "exit"
```

WinSCP GUI can [generate a script/batch-file template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) for you.

Some resources:

- Guide to [automating transfers from SFTP server with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation);
- [Downloading the latest file with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).

---

Another option is [PuTTY `pscp`](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter5.html). It's less flexible than WinSCP, but can be just enough for your needs:

```
pscp username@example.com:TBD_7dayExport_*.csv TBD_7dayExport.csv
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! with the file on my local server I'll just run a variant of ren "TBD*.csv" "TBD.csv" to get it how I need it.